# Outofrange exception when removing items form listview

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a listview which has multiple rows and check boxes is enabled I tried to wrote a code that remove item when I unchecked the item checkbox as it is checked by default
In the itemcheck event

```
If(list.Focused == true)
{
If (e.newvalue == checkState.unchecked)
 {
 list.items.removeAt( e.index);
 list.Refresh();
}
}
```

I got a outofrange exception  and 1 is not a valid for index 
'1' refer to the index of the item I removed

Comment: It seems ok to me. Can you check, is this event not getting called more than one time for any mistake?

Comment: The exception in the main method of the program not in the event

Comment: What you mean by main method. Can you share relevant code

Comment: The exception is come from Application.Run (new form ());

Comment: I think the code you shared do not have any problem. May be you have to share the right segment of code. If not sure, then post complete form code.

Comment: This exception thrown because I removed an item from an event handled this item is try to run the same code from btn and working correctly

Comment: Here is the solution in check event you have current value and new value the new value not be applied till the check event is complete if you delete the item the class throw outofrange as it is try to assign a property of deleted item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in check event you have current value and new value the new value not be applied till the check event is complete if you delete the item the class throw outofrange as it is try to assign a property of deleted item
You can use a list  to add the items in and in the event checked remove items and clear the list

Answer (score 0):

You have to test if index is in range (because the collection shrink). Add this test before removing elements :

```
if(list.items.count < e.index && e.index > 0)
```

Comment: How this code working if the index is 0  and how index > count

Comment: Maybe sometime your event is triggered twice. In this case, the e.index doesn't exist in the ListView anymore..

Comment: It give exception before end the event the event assigned by lambda expretion

Comment: I don't see any lambda expression, please post your all code. Also, you could try to suppress by object using remove instead of removeat...

Comment: Read the last comment by me on the post